# Yii2 Как правильно обращаться к данным связанной таблицы?

Tags: mysql, yii2, activerecord

Есть таблица Событие где записаны несколько id пользователей из таблицы Users в одной записи
Например: 
Журналист(id_j) - Пользователь 1, 
Редактор(id_red) - пользователь 2, 
Водитель (id_driver) - Пользователь 3, 
Оператор (id_cam) - пользователь 4
Как обращаться к таблице users, 
Если я хочу : id_j.event = users.surname, id_red = user.surname и.т.д 
Если возможно только :
$event = Event::findone($id);
$event->users->surname;

Comment: Без структуры таблиц сложно понять суть вопроса. Отобрази структуру таблиц и какие данные необходимо получить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут в твоей модели для каждой связи нужно запилить свой релейшн и потом отдельно собирать модели для них.

В модели Event что-то типа этого:

```
public function getJ()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Users::class, ['id' => 'id_j']);
}

public function getRed()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Users::class, ['id' => 'id_red']);
}

public function getDriver()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Users::class, ['id' => 'id_driver']);
}
```

А использовать так:

```
$event = Event::find()->where(['id' => $id])->with(['j', 'red', 'driver'])->one();

$jSurname = $event->j->surname;
$redSurname = $event->red->surname;
$driverSurname = $event->driver->surname;
```

P.S.: with в данном конкретном случае использовать не обязательно так как запись одна и получится один запрос на событие и по запросу на каждого его участника, но в если искать нужно будет несколько записей (для отрисовки списка событий например), то крайне важно использовать with, так как с ним останется также один запрос на все записи событий и по одному запросу на каждого типа участников этих событий, а без него будут делаться для каждой записи отдельный запрос на каждого участника конкретного события и их может быть много.

Comment: спасибо, я еще решил эту проблему через представление